# Apache 2.4 http auth doesn't prompt credentials

Tags: apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I configured a vhost with http authentication.

ServerAdmin info@example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/webmaster/www.example.com/

```
    <Directory "/home/webmaster/www.example.com/">
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

            DirectoryIndex index.html, index.php

           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "www.example.com"
           AuthUserFile "/home/webmaster/.htpasswd"
           Require valid-user

    </Directory>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com-error.log
```

/home/webmaster/.htpasswd file was created using htpasswd command:

```
htpasswd -c /home/webmaster/.htpasswd john
```

but Apache doesn't prompt for credentials, so users can browse the website without restrictions.
No error in Apache error.log file and no errors in www.example.com-error.log  file.

any suggestions? many thanks

Piero

Answer (score 1):

You need a RequireAll statement.

```
<directory ...>
...
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require valid-user
  </RequireAll>
</directory>
```

Check [article on apache auth](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/apache-authorization/)